# Why can a $u$ substitution not be used in this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

For the integral: 
$$\int \frac{v}{2 + v} dv.$$ 
I tried to use a $u$-substitution where $u = 2 + v$, rearranging to get $v = u - 2$ and $du = dv$.  When I subbed this back in and integrated I got $\frac{2}{2 + v} + C$ when the correct answer is $v - 2\ln(2 + v) + C$.

How do I know I can't use $u$-substitution here?

Comment: You made the right substitution; you simply didn't do the resulting integration correctly.

Comment: Can you show what your integral looked like in terms of u?

Comment: $\frac{u - 2}{u} du$

Comment: You know you can write that as two fractions and then integrate?

Comment: I've made progress.  Got to $1 - \frac{2}{u} du$ but when I integrate that I get $u - 2ln[u] + c$ and with u subbed in it becomes $v + 2 - 2ln[v + 2] + c$, so there is an extra 2 in there we don't want.

Comment: 2+C is still unknown constant ... Just call 2+C, K

Comment: So if I get any constants in an integration with u-substitution they can be looked at as part of the unknown?  I guess that makes sense because you can't get a constant when you integrate until you sub in known values.

Comment: While u-substitution is a perfectly good way to work this it can also be easily done without u-substitution. Simple division gives $\frac{v}{v+2}=1-\frac{1}{v+2}$, so we then get $v-2\ln\vert v+2\vert+c$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the substitution you started with:
$$\int \frac{v}{2 + v} \, dv = \int \frac{u-2}{u} \, du = \int \left(1 - \frac{2}{u} \right) \, du = u-2\ln|u| + C =v-2\ln|2+v|+D.$$

Here is another method:

$$\int \frac{v}{2 + v} \, dv = \int \frac{2+v-2}{2 + v} \, dv = \int \left (1 - \frac{2}{2+v} \right) \, dv = v-2 \ln|2+v| + C.$$

Comment: Note that the factor of $2$ is absorbed into the constant after reverting back to $v$.

Comment: $D=2+C$ indeed.